# Laravel 3 model and 2 pivot table

Tags: laravel, pivot

help me please ((

I have models:
Post
User
Tags
and 2 pivot:
post_tags
tags_user

How write query that i can get all User that have tags in correct Post
For example Post have tag1, tag3, tag4. And i need get Users who have this tags

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one option:

```
User::select('users.*')
    ->join('tags_user', 'tags_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'tags_user.tag_id')
    ->whereIn('tags.tag', $tagArray)
    ->get()
```

Comment: many to many thanks you :) i have a big problems with relations ((( 8 hours tormented (( you save me!!!! thank you again!!!